# How do I get access to the full image data in TwinCAT?

Tags: image, twincat

I am trying to find a method to access a full frame of image data in TwinCAT. Looking at:

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf7xxx_tc3_vision/6997345803.html&id=

It seems that I am able to access only one row at a time, and that is a waste of time, in this case. My purpose is to access the image data from a continuously running camera and store that data on disk one full frame at a time.

Any suggestions are welcome - thank you!

BR,
Rainer

Comment: Did you look at examples? [https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf7xxx_tc3_vision/4842534667.html&id=](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf7xxx_tc3_vision/4842534667.html&id=)
 Here is the function block's [link](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf7xxx_tc3_vision/13372836491.html&id=4982890699104163931).
Never worked with images in TC though, so can't give you any pointers for usage.

Comment: Thanks, but yes, I did look at those. Basically, they allow you to save a single image. I need to save a sequence of images to a binary file, so these methods don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

Use:

```
F_VN_ExportImageSize()
```

to get the required buffer size (in bytes) to store the image data.

And then

```
F_VN_ExportImage()
```

to export the image data into that buffer (e.g. an array).